# Passing parameters on onChange of html select

Tags: javascript, html, select, onchange

lets say i have got two html pages which both contain the same select box:

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location =    this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="/site1.php">Site1</option>
<option value="/site2.php">Site2</option>
</select>
```

I am looking for a way to pass the value of selectedIndex to the next page, so I can use it at the second page select box too. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can pass by POST, GET, COOKIE, SESSION, localStorage

Comment: The problem is when i am passing it via php, i am not able to set selectedindex via javascript because i have no access to php variables.

Answer (score 1):

**localStorage**

Store:

```
localStorage.userEdits=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
```

Get, on the other page :

```
var yourIndex = localStorage.userEdits;
```

**hash**

Set:

```
window.location.href="yourURL#index="+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
```

Get:

```
var yourIndex=window.location.hash.replace("index=","").parseInt();
```

Comment: It is a valid solution but not for my scenario, since the website will be used by older internetbrowsers.

Comment: Thanks, but for me it seems to be not an elegant way because i also pass other $get variables.

Comment: @Dede1989 Oh, doesn't suit? But it works, didn't expect you want an *elegant* adress!

Answer (score 0):

You can use query parameters:

```
window.location = 'YOUR_URL?selectedIndex=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

Using query params forces you to parse them. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) (you can do just fine with pure JS).

Comment: Look at my first answer :)